# Joining two ranges into 2d array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix, range

How do I join two ranges into a 2d array as such in ruby? Using zip doesn't provide the result I need.

```
(0..2) and (0..2)
# should become => [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2], [1,0],[1,1],[1,2], [2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help, you need to show what you've tried. Stack Overflow is a "help me debug my code site", not a "write code for me site". See "[ask]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm puzzled. Here it is a day after the question was posted and nobody has suggested the obvious: [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
[*0..2].product [*1..3]
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a built in method for this: [repeated_permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation).

```
(0..2).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).to_a
```

Comment: The square grid would be 3x3, which is probably what he wanted. If not, then he can chop off the last row.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question: "How do I join two ranges into a 2d array...?" (notwithstanding the example). All the other answers assume that the two ranges are not necessarily the same range.

Answer (score 0):

```
range_a = (0..2)
range_b = (5..8)

def custom_join(a, b)
    a.inject([]){|carry, a_val| carry += b.collect{|b_val| [a_val, b_val]}}
end

p custom_join(range_a, range_b)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]]
```

Comment: Check out `each_with_object`. It'll clean up the code in the block used by `inject`.

Answer (score 0):

straight forward solution:

```
range_a = (0..2)
range_b = (5..8)

def custom_join(a, b)
    [].tap{|result| a.map{|i| b.map{|j| result << [i, j]; } } }
end
p custom_join(range_a, range_b)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, this will do it:

```
a = (0...2).to_a
b = (0..2).to_a
result = []
a.each { |ae| b.each { |be| result << [ae, be] } }
p result
# => [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```